# Playwright how to work with re-usable methods in tests

Tags: javascript, playwright, playwright-test

I want to create methods and re-use them in tests for API testing.

Here is my scenario and code

```
// subscriptionApitests.spec.js

import { getSubscriptionsFromAPI } from "./subscriptionapi.js";
test("get subscriptions from subscription API by calling function", async ({ request }) => {
  // I want to call the following function which in return will do the request.get call and get the response
  const apiBaseUrl = "apiv3.apifootball.com/?action=get_countries"
  const response = await getSubscriptionsFromAPI(request, apiBaseUrl);
  console.log(response);
  
});
```

```
//subscriptionapi.js
import { test, expect } from "@playwright/test";

async function getSubscriptionsFromAPI(request,apiURL) {
    const response = await request.get(apiURL, {
        headers: {
          // We set this header.
          "X-Auth-Token": "abcdef",
        },
      });
    
      
      console.log(response.status());
      console.log(response);
      //return response;
  }
  
  export { getSubscriptionsFromAPI };
```

And I get response.status 404
and for response I get

APIResponse: 404 Not Found
Date: Wed, 29 Nov 2023 10:35:47 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: close
Server: nginx/1.24.0
X-Powered-By: PHP/8.1.8
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
X-Request-ID:
Content-Encoding: gzip

However when I do not call the getSubscriptionsFromAPI
and do a request.get call inside the test case, I get the right result and status 200
as following

APIResponse: 200 OK
Date: Wed, 29 Nov 2023 10:37:38 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: close
Server: nginx/1.24.0
X-Powered-By: PHP/8.1.8
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
X-Request-ID: e8c170fe-664a-49dd-8e3d-1ab8373a92ee
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Content-Encoding: gzip

Comment: I guess your context is not available at your method. Your api request is emitted by ```page``` which seems not be present at your method. I recommend either ```fixtures``` or ```.beforeAll``` where you prepare your request. It can be your request does not have the required data which you have to pass to your context if necessary. [ref API testing](https://playwright.dev/docs/api-testing), which means you have to reuse the authentication state

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by implementing the following structure

```js
// subscriptionabi.js

import { test, expect, APIRequestContext } from "@playwright/test";
import "dotenv/config";

export class SubscriptionAPI {
  constructor(request) {
    this.reqContext = request;
    this.baseURL = process.env.API_BASEURL;
    this.endPoint = "/subscriptions";
  }

  async getSubscriptionsFromAPI() {
    const response = await this.reqContext.get(
      `${this.baseURL}${this.endPoint}`,
      {
        headers: {
          // We set this header.
          "X-Auth-Token": "abcdef",
        },
      }
    );
    const jsonidresponse = await response.json();
    expect(response).toBeOK();
    console.log(typeof response);
    expect(response.status()).toBe(200);
    return jsonidresponse;
  }
```

and then calling the function from .spec file from within the test as following

```js
import { test, expect } from "@playwright/test";
import { SubscriptionAPI } from "../../../utils/subscriptionapi.js";


test("Create a subscription with API ", async ({
  request,
}) => {
  const subscriptionApi = new SubscriptionAPI(request);
  // call the method
  const response = await subscriptionApi.createSubscriptionFromAPI();
});
```